# World of Warcraft trial link appeared in my account management but doesn't do anything

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Before, if you didn't have latest the WoW expansion, there would be a little panel with options such as buying an expansion or trying a trial of it for 10 days inside your account.

Now it's gone. All I see is this Diablo 3 offer, but a "Free trial" link appeared in the list of things you can do with your account (when you click on your WoW in the list of games). The problem is that it doesn't work. It links to nothing. When you press it nothing happens.

Also, can't you usually get 7 days free for WoW's birthday? I thought that was today, but I can't find a link for it.

EDIT: I have starter edition and BC's trial would reset after some time, so I was able to level to 70 like that.

Comment: So you dont actually own BC and just got to lvl 70 during a BC trial? if thats the case I dont think they would allow you to do another BC trial or a LK trial since you dont own a copy of BC, or a Cata trial since you own neither of the previous expansions

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! I've reworded the part about WoW's anniversary gifts because we try to avoid asking questions that are localized in time; good questions will be up on the site for a long time, and "today" when they read it most likely won't be "today" when you asked it.

Answer (score 1):

Burning Crusade is now obsolete. Literally. If you previously did not own BC you now do, for free. You might say it's now the original game.

If you're going to get 7 free days, if I'm not mistaken, such freebies are given at the END of your subscription, not during, but it's been a few years since I actually paid attention to stuff like that so I'm not 100% sure on that one.

As for your trial account link being broken, that's an odd one. It's probably just broken for right now, and will work again later. The Blizzard websites are subject to maintenance very often (once a week on Tuesday, as you should know) and because of the high traffic they always get coupled with the frequent maintenance. Stuff is always breaking/being fixed.